# React array loop not generation HTML

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm building a loop according to the amount of data in my array. The console.log shows that the array has data, but it is not building the HTML in the browser.

```
<div className="row">
    {images.map((values, index) => {
            console.log(values);
        const base64Data = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${values.img}`;
        return (
            <div key={index} className="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a href="#" className="fancybox" rel="ligthbox">
                    <img 
                        src={base64Data}
                        className="zoom img-fluid " 
                        alt={values.caption}
                    />
                </a>
            </div>
        );
    })}
</div>
```

I can see that in the `console.log(values)` it logs 10 objects with img and caption for each object. However, the the divs are not being displayed.

[image]

Here is how the images array is built. The componentDidMount loads it from redux. Then, I have a second check in the componentDidUpdate.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
            event: this.props.location.state.values,
            images: []
        };
}

componentDidMount = async () => {
   this.props.onLoadImage(this.state.event.images, this.state.event.id);
   this.setState({ images: this.props.images });
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.images !== this.props.images){
        this.setState({ images: this.props.images });
    }
}
```

I console log the state.images in the render() method and it shows 3 times:

```
Array[] // empty
Array(10)
Array[] // empty again
```

Why is it being empty?

Comment: console log `images` before the loop and show us the output. What you're describing here is not possible so I assume the `images` array is actually empty or your `values` item does not have an `img` key and you get a bunch of errors

Comment: Perhaps you could expand this into a runnable example with real data that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I just added more details on how I populate the images array

Comment: 1. Shouldn't there be an await in front of this.props.onLoadImage?
2. I think what's happening here is. You get the images, as is evident by the console.log, the component renders again, the componentDidMount gets called again and since we are missing the "await" the setState gets called immediately. I could be wrong here.
3. From where are you getting this.props.images?

Comment: I'm getting the props.mage from my store action. It uses axios to do a GET request. I put an await there, but still same issue

Comment: It first console.log(empt array) from the render() method. Then, it show console.log('here') that I inserted in the componentDidMount(). Then, it show again a log with an empty array from the render(). Finally, it shows the array with 10 elements from the render()

Answer (score 0):

If **console.log(values)** shows array of 10 objects, you need to map this **values** object.

Comment: I think I did map in the lines ```const base64Data = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${values.img}`;``` and ```alt={values.caption}```

Comment: I mean you images object seems like an array. so you need to iterate it and like `values.map((value,index) => {...}` )

Comment: It is what I do on the line ```{images.map((values, index) => {``` The array is images